# How to store money in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I've created an elasticsearch index and my current mapping stores the dollar amount of an item as a string.  This is proving to be difficult as I can't search/filter on this value correctly.

```
GET catalog/product/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "range": {
      "price": {
        "from": 230.0,
        "to": 300.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where price is mapped as a string.  I used a string because going from a python decimal value, I've had issues where this value suddenly gets values at something like 17.989999999999999999998789.  This only happens sometimes but I don't wanna get into the issue of going from a python decimal to a java double/float (so I just str() the thing).

Any thoughts on a better approach?  Should I bite the bullet and map the price to a double or a float?

Comment: Problem is that ElasticSearch has no `decimal` type so it is probably being converted to a `float`. Multiply by 100 and store as cents, then convert application-side? Bye bye precision issues.

Comment: That's a great idea.  If you answer, I could mark it as such.  The only issue is returning a lot of data, looping over all those items could be expensive (slow) application side.  I could use a ES script but that's slow too I thought.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the first answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This occurs because ElasticSearch has no built-in type for decimals or currency, so your value is likely being converted to a `float` and suffering from floating point precision issues.

You should be able to get around this by simply storing the value as a `long` (e.g. the number of cents rather than dollars) and converting to and from your `decimal` application-side.

Since you'll only ever do this conversion for values you are already enumerating, the performance impact should be negligible.

Answer (score 22):

In newer version (checked for 5.0), probably the best option is to use `scaled_float` with `scaling_factor = 100` like in their example:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "number_of_bytes": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "time_in_seconds": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "scaled_float",
          "scaling_factor": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find their [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html) here.

Comment: how what is the syntax to add the data for a scaled_float data type. I am getting the error
`
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "failed to parse"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Field [val] misses required parameter [scaling_factor]"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
`

Comment: Had the same problem: the mapping correlates to a specific type (like "my_type") in the sample above. When using the High-Level-Rest-Client, it always creates the mappings under the new default "_doc" type. When inserting data using another type you get the error. After changing the insert to the _doc type the error was gone

Comment: there are precision issues related to scaled_float type so it should not be used for finance fields/attributes https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32570

Comment: @dgt it looks like the precision issues were fixed in 7.0 around Jan 2019 from that issue you linked to